# unable to import pyglet when "installed"

Tags: python, import, pip, pyglet

complete python (and programming) beginner here. I am trying to install and import the pyglet module on my mac. I initially installed it using pip, and it seemed to work, at least I got no errors returned, but when I try to import it using pycharm I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/Training/Training File.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyglet ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyglet'
```

When I tried to install it again, after getting this error, I get this from the command line:

```
MacBook:bin me$ python -m pip install pyglet Requirement already satisfied: pyglet in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages MacBook:bin me$
```

So it seems it's already installed, no?

Finally, I tried to install it using the setup.py command, which was the recommendation in the README file. I get this:

```
MacBook:~ me$ sudo python setup.py install  python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory MacBook:~ me$
```

Can anyone tell what is going on?

Comment: Are you using python 3 or 2 ?

Comment: setup.py isn't a command... You needed to clone that repository, cd into the directory, *then* run setup

Comment: Also, `in /Library/Python/2.7`.. You didn't set Pycharm to use Python2

Answer (score 0):

You might run your script in python 3. But the pyglet you have installed for python 2. Try,

```
pip3 install pyglet
```

Comment: This is what I got: MacBook:~me$ cd /usr/bin/
MacBook:bin me$ python -m pip3 install pyglet
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip3

Comment: What is the version of python ?

Comment: Do I need to download/install pip for python 3?

Comment: I am using python 3.

Comment: You should install pip3 (pip for python3) and install the pyglet

Comment: open terminal and type ```python3 get-pip.py```

Comment: Python3 comes with pip now

Answer (score 0):

I think it worked! I used

```
python3 -m pip install python
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to install python from python?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pyglet
```